# n indistinguishable balls are to be arranged in N distinguishable boxes

Tags: probability

Suppose that n indistinguishable balls are to be arranged in N distinguishable boxes so that each distinguishable arrangement is equally likely. If $n \geq N$, show that the probability no box will be empty is given by

$\frac{(\begin{matrix}
  n-1 \\
  N-1 \\
 \end{matrix})}{(\begin{matrix}
  N+n-1 \\
  N-1 \\
\end{matrix})}$.

I am supposed to use intuition and nothing more.

Comment: Are you familiar with the *stars and bars* argument that establishes the size of the sample space (the denominator)?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** This uses a [**Stars and Bars** argument,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars) actually, two of them, Please see the Wikipedia article for details.

For the denominator, we want the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_N=n$$
in non-negative integers.

For the numerator, you want the number of solutions of the same equation in positive integers.

The Wikipedia article gives formulas both for the number of non-negative solutions and for the number of positive solutions. There is a reasonably thorough explanation of why the formulas are correct.