# When to use which counting principle to calculate probabilites in balls and bins problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-explanation, balls-in-bins

I recently ran into problems understanding when to use which combinatorical counting principle concerning "balls and bins" problems. I am not 100% (maybe 80%) sure if I have understood it correctly, so I will try to summarize my thoughts on that. I would really appreciate it if someone can confirm that I have understood it properly. I know there are already dozens of balls and bins questions but I haven't found any which explicitly adresses my issue. Maybe those questions are closest but do not fully answer my problem:

[Equal probabilities in each count in stars and bars](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481937/579544)

[Sorting undistinguishable balls - $l$-many in one slot - check my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3454940/579544)
(was asked by me and made me aware that I had some misconceptions of counting principles and probabilities)

---

Let's say we have $5$ balls and $3$ numbered bins. We now look at different situations where we want to calculate the probability of a certain outcome.

1.) The balls are **indistinguishable** and thrown successively at the bins. It is equally probable to hit any bin. What is the probability of the two events

$A= (bin_1: 1~ ball,bin_2: 2~ balls,bin_3: 2~balls)$ and $B= (bin_1: 5~ balls,bin_2: 0~ balls,bin_3: 0~balls)$ ?

**My answer:** The sample space is $\Omega =\{(\omega_1, \omega_2,...,\omega_5)| \omega_i$ is the bin of the $i$-th throw $\}$. So the cardinality of the corresponding sample space $\Omega$ is: $3^5$. Hence, $P(B) = \frac{1}{3^5}$. I am not quite sure what $P(A)$ is, but it must be definitely **greater** than $P(B)$!

---

2.) The balls are **indistinguishable** and will simultanously appear in any bin. It's like pouring balls over the bins and every bin is equally probable for each ball. Again, what is the probability of the two events

$A= (bin_1: 1~ ball,bin_2: 2~ balls,bin_3: 2~balls)$ and $B= (bin_1: 5~ balls,bin_2: 0~ balls,bin_3: 0~balls)$?

**My answer:** Due to the specific setting we must change the sample space $\Omega$. It becomes: $\Omega =\{(\omega_1, \omega_2,\omega_3)| \omega_i$ is the number of balls in the $i$-th bin$\}$. The cardinality of $\Omega$ is: ${3+5-1 \choose 5}$ and the probabilities of the two events are $P(A)= P(B)=\frac{1}{{3+5-1 \choose 5}}$.

---

3.)Now the balls are **distinguishable** and thrown successively at the bins. It is equally probable to hit any bin. What is the probability of the two events $A$ and $B$?

**My answer:** the same as in 1.)

What do you think of my answers?

Comment: How is 1) different from 2)? I don't see. Btw, you may use coefficients in expansion of [$(a+b+c)^5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E5) where a,b,c are the bins and the power is number of balls for the numerator where denominator is $3^5$, e.g. 1A) is $\frac{30}{3^5}$ and 1B) is $\frac{1}{3^5}$. For 3) use 5-digit ternary number where the digit number is a ball number and the digit is bin number.

Comment: Most real-world probability questions counting equal probability results are in effect distinguishable balls into distinguishable bins, and then perhaps sums of these results if we do not care to distinguish. Your answer for (2)B of $\frac1{21}$ looks obviously wrong and should be $\frac1{27}$ or perhaps $\frac3{27}$ for "all balls in one bin"

Comment: @Henry, why is $P(B)$ in 2.) wrong? My book says that all possibilities for sorting $k$ indistinguishable objects in $n$ boxes is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$. I dont see why it should be $\frac{1}{27}$.

Comment: @Philipp The $21$ possibilities are not equally probable. Let's try a simpler example: putting $3$ balls into $2$ bins.  Your method would suggest the probability all three balls were in either of the bins and none in the other (as opposed to two in one and one in the other) was $\frac14+\frac14=\frac12$.  Can you describe a physical experiment where that happens?

Comment: @Henry, yes I understand your point but I thought that my specific setting in 2.) would be such an experiment. In the second link I posted in my question another user explained it this way.

Comment: Your choice, but that looks hypothetical rather than something that you could implement simply with actual balls and bins

Comment: @Henry, yes that should be just a hypothetical experiment because I am looking for an example where you Use this way to calculate the probability. Or do you have a more realistic example where you calculate the probability using ${3+5-1\choose 5}$ in the denominator?

Comment: I am saying no such example is realistic.  You could write the patterns on pieces of paper, then choose a piece of paper at random and then follow its pattern, or you could organise the balls and bin dividers at random without seeing whether a thing was a ball or a divider, but I do not see either of those as realistic

Comment: @Henry, I found this question  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499230/579544 which is kind of similar and has the same set up like my problem. However, they do use ${k+n-1\choose k}$ as the denominator when calculatibg the probability. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Philipp old post, but to answer this the OP there explicitly includes the phrase "*so that each distinguishable arrangement is equally likely.*"